Organizing code for interdependent modules
Purpose: I'm writing a JS library that will consist of a core class which will be extended by submodules. Those submodules need to be able to plug independently on this core and have access to a few utilities imported by the core (api endpoints and functions, l10n strings and methods, ...).
As each component is executed, data is progressively added to the this of the subclass (thus the one of the main class), and I'd like every utility to have access to that this dynamically so it always has the latest version of the variables attached to it.
This is why I can't call utility classes with a parameter (this.apis = new Apis(this) will create a copy of this at the moment of instanciation but not update it afterwards).
I have thought of Proxies, but it doesn't seem to be relevant in that case. So far, the best I have found to do -and that works- is by using any_method.bind(this). However, I don't know how to bind a full class so that all the methods will have access to this and not have to bind each method separately.
Would anyone have any suggestion for a clean reactive system for my use case?
If not, maybe anyone can tell me how to bind(this) a whole class?
Thanks a lot

I hope you are always successful.
I hope I have understood your point correctly.
I can suggest two solutions:
My first suggestion is simple.
You can use reflection (like Object.getOwnPropertyNames) in the class constructor to find all the class methods and bind them to the desired object.


class BaseClass {
  constructor() {

    this._bindMethods();
  }

  _bindMethods() {
    const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    const methodNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype);

    for (const name of methodNames) {
      if (name !== 'constructor' && typeof this[name] === 'function') {
        this[name] = this[name].bind(this);
      }
    }
  }
}

 
class SubModule extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.someData = 'Hello, world!';
  }

  printData() {
    console.log(this.someData);
  }

  async fetchData() {
 
    console.log('Fetching data...');
  }
}

const instance = new SubModule();
const { printData } = instance;
printData();




This means that you need to use bind separately for each method, and
the bound methods can access the current class data.

My second suggestion:
If submodules need to access the latest state of the main class's data and methods in real-time (even if the structure or data changes during execution), the Proxy solution is ideal.
My suggestion is to combine these two methods:


class BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    this._bindMethods();
    return new Proxy(this, {
      get(target, prop) {
        // اول داده‌ها و متدهای عادی را بررسی می‌کنیم
        if (prop in target) return target[prop];
        // برای ابزارهای دینامیک یک پیغام یا مقدار پیش‌فرض بازمی‌گردد
        return (...args) => {
          throw new Error(`Method or property "${prop}" is not defined.`);
        };
      },
    });
  }

  _bindMethods() {
    const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    const methodNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(prototype);

    for (const name of methodNames) {
      if (name !== 'constructor' && typeof this[name] === 'function') {
        this[name] = this[name].bind(this);
      }
    }
  }
}

class SubModule extends BaseClass {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.data = 'Hello, Reactive System!';
  }

  printData() {
    console.log(this.data);
  }

  updateData(newData) {
    this.data = newData;
  }
}

// استفاده:
const instance = new SubModule();
instance.printData(); // "Hello, Reactive System!"

const { printData } = instance;
printData(); // بدون خطا

console.log(instance.someUndefinedMethod()); // خطا: Method or property "someUndefinedMethod" is not defined.



I hope these solutions help you.
